# Number of some zero-one matrices

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a_n$ be the number of $n\times n$ zero-one matrices such that in any row and any column there are exactly two 1.

What is the value of $a_n$ in terms of $n$ ?

Comment: trying to find a recursion relation.

Comment: The reason I am asking is, if you write down your steps, somebody may pick it up and continue from that, people will be more willing to help, you will get an answer much faster. BTW, I have tried and basically nothing worked would also be a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: Are the matrices of size $n\times n$?

Comment: yes matrices are of size $n\times n$

Comment: Figure it out for the first eight or so values of $n$ and try the sequence at O.E.I.S.; it's almost certain to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [OEIS A001499](http://oeis.org/A001499); the entry has numerous references. The first few non-zero values are $a_2=1$, $a_3=6$, $a_4=90$, $a_5=2040$, $a_6=67950$, and $a_7=3110940$. The entry gives the exact formula

$$a_n=\frac{n!(n-1)\Gamma\left(n-\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}\cdot{_1F_1}\left[2-n;\frac32-n;-\frac12\right]\;,$$

the asymptotic formula

$$a_n\sim 2\sqrt{\pi}\left(\frac{n}e\right)^{2n+\frac12}\;,$$

and the recurrence

$$a_n=\frac12n(n-1)^2\left((2n-3)a_{n-2}+(n-2)^2a_{n-3}\right)\;.$$

Comment: What is the $_1F_1$ function ?

Comment: @AA: It’s the [confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), about which I know very little.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful references.

Comment: @AA: You’re welcome.